# Android MediaCodec flush after MediaExtractor seekTo and AudioTrack flush behaviour unexpectedly bad

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, audiotrack, mediaextractor

I am using the combination of AudioTrack, MediaCodec and MediaExtractor to decode and play music.

As per [the document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#flush%28%29),

> In order to start decoding data that's not adjacent to previously submitted data (i.e. after a seek) it is necessary to flush() the decoder. Any input or output buffers the client may own at the point of the flush are immediately revoked, i.e. after a call to flush() the client does not own any buffers anymore.

I am calling flush after seek, so that i should also call mAudioTrack.flush();

Though flush is called, audioTrack plays some part of previously written data and continues from newly written data.

Without calling decoder.flush, possibly hearing noticeable  glitches in audio playback. So how to achieve this **instantaneous flush and continue playback of newly written data**?

Code Snippet:

Updated code

```
do {
                int codedbufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
                if (codedbufferIndex >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer codecInput = inputBuffers[codedbufferIndex];
                    synchronized (playerState) {
                        if (seek) {
                            extractor.seekTo(seekTo,
                                    MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
                        //  audioTrack.pause();
                        //  audioTrack.stop();
                        //  audioTrack.flush();
                            decoder.flush();
                            seek = false;
                        //  audioTrack.play();
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    read = extractor.readSampleData(codecInput, offset);
                    if (read < 0) {
                        if (extractor.hasCacheReachedEndOfStream())
                            Log.e(TAG, "extractor.hasCacheReachedEndOfStream()");
                        break;
                    }
                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(codedbufferIndex, offset, read,
                            presentationTimeUs, (read > 0) ? 0
                                    : MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    int decodedDataBufIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info,
                            2000);
                    if (decodedDataBufIndex >= 0) {
                        ByteBuffer codecOutput = outputBuffers[decodedDataBufIndex];
                        byte[] atInput = new byte[info.size];
                        codecOutput.get(atInput);
                        codecOutput.clear();
                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decodedDataBufIndex, false);
                        if(info.offset != 0){
                            Log.e(TAG,"info.offset = "+String.valueOf(info.offset));
                        }
                        audioTrack.write(atInput, /*0*/info.offset, info.size);
                        extractor.advance();
                    } else if (decodedDataBufIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                        MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "newFormat: "
                                        + newFormat
                                                .getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "newFormat: "
                                        + String.valueOf(newFormat
                                                .getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE)));

                        Log.e(TAG, "Inside INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED");
                        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 32768,
                                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                        audioTrack.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG,"codedbufferIndex is  "+String.valueOf(codedbufferIndex));
                }
            } while (read >= 0);
```

Comment: do you call advance() after making a seek?

Comment: @Marlon, yes i did!, (Edited the question )

Answer (score 0):

AudioTrack.flush() is no-op if not paused or stopped.

> No-op if not stopped or paused, or if the track's creation mode is not
>   MODE_STREAM.

One solution would be to lower the buffer of the AudioTrack, so the playing of the previously submitted bytes is not perceptible. In my app, I use a rather large size of 32K and it isn't bothersome.

Comment: I tried your suggestion(edited question accordingly), still it does seems the behaviour reported in OP is happening

Comment: There is no way to do what you are asking, you can not flush the AudioTrack while playing. See my additional answer.

Comment: Yes, we cannot flush while it's playing, but here my calling sequence is pause,stop,flush

Comment: Why stop()? Stop will not stop until the last bytes are played per the documentation. Use pause(), then flush(). You will have a little gap while AudioTrack is paused.

Comment: In my app, I do the seeking in two different ways. If the AudioTrack is already paused (user is seeking while not playing), I call flush() on decoder and AudioTrack. If AudioTrack is playing (user is seeking while playing), I flush() the decoder and don't call flush(), pause() or stop() on the AudioTrack. This sounds perfect to me.

Comment: Like you said, if i call flush() only on decoder and not on audiotrack,, now the creepy sound is more annoying :(

Comment: I notice only a slight static noise when seeking while playing during certain quiet sections of audio. A solution to make it perfect would be to mute the AudioTrack momentarily and then bring back the volume with a postDelayed(). Google Play Music does lower the volume like this when seeking.

Comment: But the default MediaPlayer's seek works like a charm, why can't we do that?

Comment: It should sound very close. Perhaps you are writing garbage bytes somehow with MediaCodec. Can you post your whole decoding code and maybe an audio file of what you're hearing?

Comment: I can see from what you have you are probably writing some garbage bytes during seek. audioTrack.write(atInput, 0, info.size); You need to account for info.offset.

Comment: Let me try it and report you

Comment: I tried `audioTrack.write(atInput, /*0*/info.offset, info.size);`, this is what were you saying?

Comment: I have added whole decoding loop, this may help you further investigate ; Thank you for still helping out

Comment: So what is the problem eaxctly ? Can you post a minimal running app project that demonstrates the problem?